# JObject SelectToken Unexpected character while parsing path indexer

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I need to parse an API json response to pull out a certain value.  This method has always worked well for me without issue until tonight.  When attempting to execute this code:

```
JObject oR = JObject.Parse(response2.Content);                   

if (oR.SelectToken("[response][0][assignment][current][channelId]") != null)
{
    ChannelId = oR.SelectToken("[response][0][assignment][current][channelId]").ToString();
}
```

I receive this error:

```
Unexpected character while parsing path indexer: r
```

Here is the full json response from the api I'm attempting to parse:

```
{
    "response": [
        {
            "id": 268633,
            "parentOrderId": 0,
            "orderTypeCode": "SO",
            "reference": "#351569",
            "version": 3,
            "state": {
                "tax": "READY"
            },
            "orderStatus": {
                "orderStatusId": 41,
                "name": "Ready to Ship"
            },
            "tax": {
                "errors": []
            },
            "orderPaymentStatus": "PAID",
            "stockStatusCode": "SOA",
            "allocationStatusCode": "AAA",
            "shippingStatusCode": "SNS",
            "placedOn": "2021-10-07T18:53:54.000-05:00",
            "createdOn": "2021-10-07T18:54:12.000-05:00",
            "updatedOn": "2021-10-07T18:57:43.000-05:00",
            "createdById": 4,
            "priceListId": 3,
            "priceModeCode": "EXC",
            "delivery": {
                "deliveryDate": "2021-10-06T19:00:00.000-05:00",
                "shippingMethodId": 9
            },
            "invoices": [
                {
                    "invoiceReference": "",
                    "taxDate": "2021-10-07T00:00:00.000-05:00",
                    "dueDate": "2021-10-06T19:00:00.000-05:00"
                }
            ],
            "currency": {
                "accountingCurrencyCode": "USD",
                "orderCurrencyCode": "USD",
                "exchangeRate": "1.000000",
                "fixedExchangeRate": true
            },
            "totalValue": {
                "net": "14.10",
                "taxAmount": "1.16",
                "baseNet": "14.10",
                "baseTaxAmount": "1.16",
                "baseTotal": "15.26",
                "total": "15.26"
            },
            "assignment": {
                "current": {
                    "staffOwnerContactId": 0,
                    "projectId": 0,
                    "channelId": 3,
                    "leadSourceId": 0,
                    "teamId": 0
                }
            },
            "parties": {
                "customer": {
                    "contactId": 748240,
                    "addressFullName": "John Doe",
                    "companyName": "",
                    "addressLine1": "225 N First ST",
                    "addressLine2": "",
                    "addressLine3": "My Town",
                    "addressLine4": "Texas",
                    "postalCode": "76082-2583",
                    "country": "United States",
                    "telephone": "+1900MIXALOT",
                    "mobileTelephone": "",
                    "fax": "",
                    "email": "john.doe@yahoo.com",
                    "countryId": 223,
                    "countryIsoCode": "US",
                    "countryIsoCode3": "USA"
                },
                "delivery": {
                    "addressFullName": "John Doe",
                    "companyName": "",
                    "addressLine1": "225 N First ST",
                    "addressLine2": "",
                    "addressLine3": "My Town",
                    "addressLine4": "Texas",
                    "postalCode": "76082-2583",
                    "country": "United States",
                    "telephone": "+1900MIXALOT",
                    "mobileTelephone": "",
                    "fax": "",
                    "email": "john.doe@yahoo.com",
                    "countryId": 223,
                    "countryIsoCode": "US",
                    "countryIsoCode3": "USA"
                },
                "billing": {
                    "contactId": 748240,
                    "addressFullName": "John Doe",
                    "companyName": "",
                    "addressLine1": "225 N First ST",
                    "addressLine2": "",
                    "addressLine3": "My Town",
                    "addressLine4": "Texas",
                    "postalCode": "76082-2583",
                    "country": "United States",
                    "telephone": "+1900MIXALOT",
                    "mobileTelephone": "",
                    "fax": "",
                    "email": "john.doe@yahoo.com",
                    "countryId": 223,
                    "countryIsoCode": "US",
                    "countryIsoCode3": "USA"
                }
            },
            "orderRows": {
                "600995": {
                    "orderRowSequence": "10",
                    "productId": 30727,
                    "productName": "Mens Wrangler Sport Western Plaid Snap - M",
                    "productSku": "395802",
                    "quantity": {
                        "magnitude": "1.0000"
                    },
                    "itemCost": {
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "value": "11.2500"
                    },
                    "productPrice": {
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "value": "24.9900"
                    },
                    "discountPercentage": "0.00",
                    "rowValue": {
                        "taxRate": "9.5000",
                        "taxCode": "T",
                        "taxCalculator": "manual",
                        "rowNet": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "value": "4.9900"
                        },
                        "rowTax": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "value": "0.4000"
                        },
                        "taxClassId": 2
                    },
                    "productOptions": {
                        "Top Size": "M",
                        "Color": "Multi"
                    },
                    "nominalCode": "4000",
                    "composition": {
                        "bundleParent": false,
                        "bundleChild": false,
                        "parentOrderRowId": 0
                    },
                    "externalRef": "10197546795147",
                    "clonedFromId": 0
                },
                "600997": {
                    "orderRowSequence": "30",
                    "productId": 1001,
                    "productName": "Shipping: UPS SurePost",
                    "productSku": "",
                    "quantity": {
                        "magnitude": "1.0000"
                    },
                    "itemCost": {
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "value": "0.0000"
                    },
                    "productPrice": {
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "value": "9.1100"
                    },
                    "discountPercentage": "0.00",
                    "rowValue": {
                        "taxRate": "9.5000",
                        "taxCode": "T",
                        "taxCalculator": "manual",
                        "rowNet": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "value": "9.1100"
                        },
                        "rowTax": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "value": "0.7600"
                        },
                        "taxClassId": 2
                    },
                    "nominalCode": "4030",
                    "composition": {
                        "bundleParent": false,
                        "bundleChild": false,
                        "parentOrderRowId": 0
                    },
                    "clonedFromId": 0
                },
                "600996": {
                    "orderRowSequence": "20",
                    "productId": 1000,
                    "productName": "Coupon: PDJA046209",
                    "productSku": "",
                    "quantity": {
                        "magnitude": "1.0000"
                    },
                    "itemCost": {
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "value": "0.0000"
                    },
                    "productPrice": {
                        "currencyCode": "USD",
                        "value": "0.0000"
                    },
                    "discountPercentage": "0.00",
                    "rowValue": {
                        "taxRate": "0.0000",
                        "taxCode": "-",
                        "taxCalculator": "brightpearl",
                        "rowNet": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "value": "0.0000"
                        },
                        "rowTax": {
                            "currencyCode": "USD",
                            "value": "0.00"
                        },
                        "taxClassId": 1
                    },
                    "productOptions": {
                        "Top Size": "S",
                        "Color": "Green"
                    },
                    "nominalCode": "4020",
                    "composition": {
                        "bundleParent": false,
                        "bundleChild": false,
                        "parentOrderRowId": 0
                    },
                    "clonedFromId": 0
                }
            },
            "warehouseId": 3,
            "acknowledged": 0,
            "costPriceListId": 1,
            "historicalOrder": false,
            "externalRef": "3912489140363",
            "installedIntegrationInstanceId": 484,
            "orderWeighting": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, I have no control over the json that is returned from the webservice API.  The best I have been able to dig up is that there is an issue with one of the json keys, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it or account for it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Your JsonPath syntax is incorrect. Integer and string keys go inside the square-brackets, not identifiers.

Comment: This page explains the JSONPath syntax https://support.smartbear.com/alertsite/docs/monitors/api/endpoint/jsonpath.html

Comment: You can also use the index operator `oR["response"][0]["assignment"]["current"]["channelId"]`

Comment: @Dai, thanks for pointing out my issue.  It was staring me in the face the whole time.  That is why sometimes it is just better to go to bed than program tired.  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct JSONPath syntax is:

```
response[0].assignment.current.channelId
```

...or use *enquoted* property names:

```
['response'][0]['assignment']['current']['channelId']
```

Personally I prefer the former syntax as it's much cleaner and easier to read.

---

Additionally, your program is also inefficient because you're evaluating the JSONPath twice. Instead use C#'s `is var` operator to store the result:

```
JObject oR = JObject.Parse(response2.Content);                   

if (oR.SelectToken("response[0].assignment.current.channelId") is JToken channelIdToken)
{
    this.ChannelId = channelIdToken.ToString();
}
```